# I implemented date range fliter in JQuery DataTable . But it is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

> I used the resources from the jQuery DataTable website and also implemented the JQuery  dataTable plugin.

> When using the Range Filter code throw jQuery error 'DateTime is not defined'

**This is Datepicker**

> I use the HTML date picker

```
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Minimum date:</td>
                    <td><input type="date" id="min" name="min"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Maximum date:</td>
                    <td><input type="date" id="max" name="max"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**This is HTML**

> I binding the data in a table  using jQuery Ajax

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table table-bordered border-primary" id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>S.No</th>
                    <th width="20%">State</th>
                    <th width="20%">District</th>
                    <th width="20%">Date</th>
                    <th>Submitted</th>
                    <th>Completed</th>
                    <th>Not Completed</th>
                    <th>Rejected</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="OpeatatorDetails">
                
            </tbody>
 </table>
```

**Here jQuery code that I have copied from Jquery Data Table website**

```
>I have uses following plugin.
<script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/datetime/1.2.0/js/dataTables.dateTime.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {

        // Create date inputs
        minDate = new DateTime($('#min'), {
            format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
        });

        maxDate = new DateTime($('#max'), {
            format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
        });

        // DataTables initialisation
        var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

        // Refilter the table
        $('#min, #max').on('change', function () {
            table.draw();
        });

    });
var minDate, maxDate;

    $.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push(
        function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
            var min = minDate.val();
            var max = maxDate.val();
            var date = new Date(data[3]);

            if (
                (min === null && max === null) ||
                (min === null && date <= max) ||
                (min <= date && max === null) ||
                (min <= date && date <= max)
            ) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    );
</script>
```

[image: Here is Image of table]